# How to create this quote box with (preferably) HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I want to add the quote box below (created in Photoshop) on my website but would love for it to be created "dynamically" with preferably HTML5/CSS3 (+ jQuery if not possible with HTML/CSS alone). Using images for the quotes is also possible, but would prefer none for the best responsive solution. Width can be fixed but height should adjust to contents within the box.

Googled and searched SO for a solution but couldn't find one.

But! .. found some html blockquote element CSS (see below and [jsbin here][1]) that does everything but the lines, but don't have the skills to get them "drawn" myself, so will appreciate if someone will help. Thanks!

[image: quote box]

---

**Update**

Getting close now!

See here: http://jsbin.com/giwafo/1/ (locked, clone to make changes)

The idea is to position a box that has the background color on top of the border on the `<blockquote>` element, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this so it adapts to the size of the quote/blockquote and is position correctly no matter what size the blockquote is.

Any ideas?

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: border + image and absolute positioning would be an easy way.

Comment: the quotes look backwards to me.

Comment: You're right, @zzzzBov - thanks. Now they are correct :)

Comment: 1. Add a border. 2. Give the quotes a width/height. 3. Position the quotes. 4. Give the quotes a background (to block the border underneath).

Comment: @Jasper Tried your idea and it works great for the top (first) quationmarks, but not for the second. Please see http://jsbin.com/giwafo/1/ (locked, clone to make changes). Any ideas?

Comment: @rassom Looks good in Chrome, what's the issue?

Comment: @Jasper Hvae a look at this: http://jsbin.com/giwafo/2/edit As you can see from the subtle backgroudn (#fafafa) around the qutoation marks, the second one is boxed downwards, thus not clearing the border lines properly. Make sense?

Comment: @rassom I'm not 100% sure what you mean but you can add padding to the `:before` and `:after` CSS so the quotes aren't so close to the edge.

Comment: @Jasper Ah yes, of course. Got it and it's working perfectly. Please provide this jsbin (http://jsbin.com/ziquzi/2/) as answer and I'll accept. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :-)

Comment: Who downwoted my question? And why? Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jasper (see comments under my question above), I resolved it. Solution can be found here: [jsbin.com/ziquzi/2](http://jsbin.com/ziquzi/2).

CSS:

```
.container {
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding: 2em;
}
blockquote {
  padding: 2em 1.5em 2em 2em;
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
}
blockquote p {
  color: #555;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid gray;    
  }
  blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  blockquote:before {
    content:"\201D";
    padding: 0 12px 11px 0;
    left: -8px;
    top: -8px;
  }
  blockquote:after {
    content:"\201C";
    padding: 9px 0 0 11px;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -7px;
  }
}
blockquote cite {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
blockquote cite:before {
  content:"\2014 \2009";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <blockquote>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <footer>
      <cite>Somebody famous</cite>
    </footer>
  </blockquote>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
 z-index: 1;
 background: white;
 padding: 2em;
}
blockquote {
 padding: 2em 1.5em 2em 2em;
 position: relative;
 color: #999;
}
blockquote p {
 color: #555;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
 blockquote {
 border: 1px solid gray;
}
 blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
 background-color:white;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-weight: 800;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 20;
}
 blockquote:before {
 content:url('http://download.easyicon.net/png/534874/32/');
 width: 34px;
 height: 31px;
 left: 2px;
 top: 2px;
 -ms-transform: rotate(178deg); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(178deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 transform: rotate(178deg);
}
 blockquote:after {
 content:url('http://download.easyicon.net/png/534874/32/');
 width: 31px;
 height: 37px;
 right: 3px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
}
blockquote cite {
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: -7px;
}
blockquote cite:before {
 content:"\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <blockquote>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    <footer> <cite>Somebody famous</cite> </footer>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

hope it can help you